# module 'docker' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

Estou utilizando o **docker-py** na versão 3.7 do Python e quando tento executar a função que a utiliza é retornado um AttributeError

Meu código:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import docker

    # Create your views here.
    def index(Request):

        client = docker.Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
        events = objdocker.events()
        for event in events:
            return HttpResponse(event)
            # and cancel from another thread
            events.close()
```

Erro recebido:

AttributeError at /docker/
module 'docker' has no attribute 'Client'

Ps. Já tentei utilizar a versão 2.7 do Python pensando que a api do docker aceitaria melhor o docker, porém, ela não é compatível.

Comment: E que documentação utilizou como base? Pois na [atual](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html), de fato, não existe uma classe chamada `Client` e sim existe uma chamada `DockerClient`.

Comment: Eu utilizei desse link https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html porém eu vi em alguns fóruns que docker.Client é mais atual, no entanto em ambos os casos o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais provável aí é que você tenha no seu projeto algum arquivo chamado `docker.py` - e o comandod e import carrega esse arquivo no lugar da biblioteca `docker` instalada no ambiente de Python.

É só renomear o arquivo que tenha esse nome no seu projeto para qualquer outra coisa, e esse erro deve sumir.